# How to disable Joomla module using code

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to develop a plugin in Joomla 2.5.6 to disable some modules in the joomla project. my aim is to disable the modules until a condition is satisfied. I need the code for disable and enable the modules in Joomla 2.5.6. Please give the code to disable and enable module in Joomla 2.5.6

Comment: Do you mean enable/disable in the admin or the front end? Also, that is a universal setting for a module. If it is enabled/disabled for one user, it will be the same for all users. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there is probably a better way to do it than using the enabled/disabled parameter.

Comment: I m searching for it now too